# How to run a Gradle task with different parameters

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle

I'd like to define a task in gradle (called `gen`) that runs the gradle task `jar` but with a fix value for `baseName`. I also want the original task `jar` to be available afterwards.

My Problem is, that I can't transfer the setting for manifest.

I tired e.g.

```
def mainFile = 'com.so.proj.App'
def filename = 'something'

jar {
    baseName filename
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainFile
    }
}

task gen (type: Jar) {
    description "Generates JAR without version number."
    doFirst {
        //archiveName = jar.baseName + "." + extension
        archiveName = filename + ".jar"
        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': mainFile
        }
    }
}
```

I thought I'm redefining the `Jar` task by using other values for archiveName and manifest.

When running `./gradlew jar` an executable JAR file is generated.

When running `./gradlew gen` a jar file is generated. Unfortunately when trying to run the program using `java -jar build/libs/something.jar` I get the error message:

java -jar build/libs/something.jar

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.so.proj.App
```

What am I doing wrong? I simply want to run the jar task with different parameters (without configuring the jar task itself, but running an alias). And what is the code doing that I wrote (I don't get an error when running the task. But what is it doing?)

Comment: you likely need to just add `with Jar` to your task gen definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `doFirst` in your gen task. You need to add a `with jar` to include all regular jar contents, which results in:

```
task gen (type: Jar) {
    description "Generates JAR without version number."
    archiveName = filename + ".jar"
    manifest {attributes 'Main-Class': mainFile}
    with jar
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for the `with`. I searched all(?) documentation pages for tasks but could not find anything. where is this documented?

Comment: I believe `with` is the groovy `with` and `with jar` uses the jar closure. But I haven't been able to find a good reference that explains this satisfactorily.

Comment: In this gave `with()` is not a Groovy method, but comes from the `Jar` class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35948697