# Whats the meaning of "with" in gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

In the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35879150 there is a `with` in the last line:

```
task gen (type: Jar) {
    description "Generates JAR without version number."
    archiveName = filename + ".jar"
    manifest {attributes 'Main-Class': mainFile}
    with jar
}
```

What is the exact meaning, and where is it documented? I couldn't find it in the gradle documentation and the `with` in groovy (http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_using_with_for_repeated_operations_on_the_same_bean) seems to be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you are calling the `with()`-method of the `Jar` class. (see the very bottom of the [Jar DSL documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:with%28org.gradle.api.file.CopySpec[]%29) and the [Jar API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#with%28org.gradle.api.file.CopySpec...%29))

> Adds the given specs as a child of this spec.

So, it's **not** the `with()`-method of Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

With `with` in this case you seem to call the closure named `jar`:

```
jar {
    baseName filename
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainFile
    }
}

task gen (type: Jar) {
    //....
    with jar
}
```

in run-time (when the builder is called) it'll be converted to:

```
task gen (type: Jar) {
    //....

  jar {
    baseName filename
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainFile
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea where the `with` is documented? I try to figure out how to learn gradle, but for several things I can't find the documentation, ...

Comment: `with` is documented in your link as well: http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_using_with_for_repeated_operations_on_the_same_bean. The point is, the `with` takes a closure as argument and runs it. This is exactly the same behavior that you see in your gradle task. You can do pretty much everything in that closure

Comment: But isn't `jar` a reference to the an instance of the `Jar` class that was generated by the Java Plugin? How can it be a closure then?

Comment: the `jar` here is the name name of the closure you have defined above, has nothing to do with `Jar` class

Comment: On http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895201/is-gradles-jar-a-method I already learned, that `jar {}` is not a function call in Gradle, but sometimes a coll of the method `getByName`. So are you saying that **`getByName` also adds a property with the name `jar` to `project`?** or **is it the JavaPlugin that add the property?** Do you have a reference? There seem to be severaly things that are hard to find in the documentation. I think this is crucial for the understanding of how gradle works - so really hope you have an answer,...

Comment: yeah, sort of. The easiest way to prove it is to rename `jar{..}` to `jarNew{..}`. 1st you get `something not found exception`, then change the `with jar` to `with jarNew` and see if it works