# Why does my jar file not not contain any class files?

Tags: gradle, jar, task, build.gradle

I'm trying to add a task (`gen` or `gen2`) to my `build.gradle` that does exactly the same as the `Jar`-task:

```
version = "0.0.1"
apply plugin: 'java'

task('gen', type: Jar) {
}

task gen2(type: Jar)
```

Running

```
gradle jar
```

generates a JAR-file that contains `.class`-files, while running

```
gradle gen
```

or

```
gradle gen2
```

generate a JAR-file that does **NOT** contain any `.class`-files.

**Whats wrong with my class definition?**

Comment: I know how to make it work. I'm not entirely sure I understand how everything works under the surface. Either add `with jar` to use exactly what jar would include or use `from` to declare what sourcesets to get classes from - you can also add includes and excludes to customize what is included.

Comment: There is no difference between your declaration of `gen` and `gen2`, you're just using two variations possible in gradle DSL.

Comment: @RaGe: Yes `gen` and `gen2` should be the same,... the `with` sometimes works, and sometimes not. In the examples on https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html they don't use `with` and claim it should work (Using `Copy` instead of `Jar`). Maybe the default config is not inherited when generating a second instance? I have no idea,... taking me already two days to find an answer.

Comment: How about just `from sourcesets...` then? I'll do a quick test and post an answer.

Comment: BTW, `copy` doesn't have any default predefined settings like `jar` does. So `with copy` doesn't add anything whereas `with jar` brings `from sourceSets.main.output` and probably a default manifest as well.

Comment: @RaGe: So these are then the defaults set by the Java Plugin while instantiating the `jar` task? That would make sense, since some of those values seem to be documented in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Comment: The `with()` is a method of the `Jar` class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35948697

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build a jar with all the classes from main, as a default `jar` task would, do this:

```
task gen2(type: Jar){
    baseName = 'gen2Jar'
    from sourceSets.main.output
}
```

You can also do `from(sourceSets.main.output){ include "package" }` to customize what packages are included.

Alternatively, to copy settings from the default `jar` task:

```
task gen(type: Jar){
    baseName = 'genJar'
    with jar
}
```

Infact you can have [both of these in the same build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/foragerr/4d211b03ad0f71ac066b). Running `gradle jar` builds default jar. `gradle gen` builds genJar.jar and `gradle gen2` builds gen2Jar.jar, all of which contain all the classes from java.main

Comment: OK, I'm slowly approaching the solution. So, the `from` is a method from the `Jar`-class, right? But where does the `sourceSets.main.output` come from, and why are additional tasks carried out when I add it to my task configuration? And why is it not necessary to add it to the configuration of the `jar` task? Thank you to accompany me,... :) I'll return the favor.

Comment: Yup: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:from(java.lang.Object, groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: `Jar` task needs `compile` task to run first, so the .class files are available to be packaged. You can see the [lifecycle and task dependencies here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/img/javaPluginTasks.png)

Comment: But why does accessing the property `sourceSets.main.output` start additional tasks, which are not startet when I'm not accessing it?

Comment: Will have to look through code to see how using output triggers additional tasks, but without running the compile and classes tasks, output will be empty (or at least outdated)

Comment: According zu `Table 45.9. Java plugin - source set properties` on https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html the property output is an Instance of `SourceSetOutput`. Maybe this is lazily instantiated causing the other tasks to run when trying to get the instance of `SourceSetOutput`.