# Why there is no .class file in my jar file created by gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build, jar, build.gradle

I create a jar file by Gradle(Ver 6.1.1) but there is no .class file in my jar file.

Created jar file contains only META-INF directory.

My build.gradle under root directory is following.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

group = 'com.test.foo'
version = '1.0.0'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
```

Then, I entered a following command.

```
$ gradle build
```

Of course there are many .java files under /src, but created jar file does not contains .class files.

I confirmed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919372/why-does-my-jar-file-not-not-contain-any-class-files), but this is not useful for me because my using command is supplied by the plugin.

Why this phenomenon is happen? What should I fix?

---

■additional info

/build/classes directory does not also created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

> Of course there are many .java files under **/src**, but created jar file does not contains .class files.

Gradle, by convention, compiles Java source files from folder `src/main/java`. Make sure to either put your files in that folder (preferred) or configure Gradle to look into `src` only.

Further reading: [Organizing Gradle Projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html)

Comment: I'm sorry for my replying late. I reconstructed folder structure to `src/main/java` and built jar file again. Then, I could create a jar file with .class files. Thank you for your useful advice!