# Is Gradles `jar` a method?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build, build.gradle

I'm using the Java Plugin in Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

I also configure the Jar-task using:

```
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}
```

If I understood it right, `jar` is a **method** which is called with a closure as the parameter. But where is this method documented? I my understandung it schuld be a method of Project.

I couldn't find it in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html and https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html and https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

Or am I wrong with my assumption that `jar` is a method?

Comment: It's there, I just searched for "jar" in your first link. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

Comment: @Dima: I can't find it on that page,... in the table I only find the description for the **task** `jar` linking to the **class** `jar`. But there is no documentation (showing e.g. the signature) of the **method** `jar`. Or is `jar` not a method? Then: Where is it documented to call the task with a closure and what's the meaning?

Comment: Not "call the task", but "configure the task". You are just giving it the attributes you want added to the jar manifest. It is all described on the page I linked to.

Comment: It definitely can not be a method of Project because Project doesn't know about plugins API. But plugin can register itself and Project will delegate processing of configuration block to the corresponding plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes and no**. The syntax is *syntactic sugar* (although in this case it makes things confusing). It is not a function `jar` that is called, but the function `tasks.getByName` that gets the name and the closure as a parameter.

On https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html it says in part `17.3. Configuring tasks` (`Example 17.9. Configuring a task - with closure`):

> This works for any task. Line 3 of the example is just a shortcut for the `tasks.getByName()` method. It is important to note that if you pass a closure to the `getByName()` method, this closure is applied to configure the task, not when the task executes.

So you can also write:

```
version = '1.0'
tasks.getByName "jar", {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably not a comprehensive answer you're looking for, but some pointers in the right direction:

The internals of the jar task don't seem to be documented in a lot of detail, so you'll have to look through source to get to what you're looking for. The jar task comes from the java plugin [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L117). Which in turn adds a task from [this class](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.groovy). This class doesn't do a whole lot beyond extending from [Jar.java](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/platform-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/jvm/tasks/Jar.java).

So it would seem the closure:

```
jar {
        ....
}
```

calls the constructor [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/platform-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/jvm/tasks/Jar.java#L49) and sets the properties defined in the jar closure. Further Jar class extends from Zip.java, while overriding the extension of the archive file, and adding a manifest property.

--

PS: This still doesn't quite help me understand `with jar` from your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878939/how-to-run-a-gradle-task-with-different-parameters), but I like your line of questioning, I'm learning a few things along the way!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I found a nice article, that should be interesting for you: http://igorpopov.io/2014/05/01/understanding-gradle/