# Get a warning when defining a function that would otherwise lead to a task configuration in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, warnings, build.gradle, strict, syntactic-sugar

I learned that configuring tasks can look like method calls ([Is Gradles `jar` a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895201/is-gradles-jar-a-method))

So, when using the java plugin, a task called `jar` is registered. In this case

```
jar {
  ...
}
```

configures the task `jar`.

Now, when I define a function named `jar`

```
def jar (Closure s) { println "closure" }
```

the same call will be a function call.

This `syntactic sugar` is really confusing for newcomers. I think there is no way to find out directly that something is a function call or a configuration call without checking the whole script (**is that right?**).

But is there a way to get a warning when I define a function that would otherwise lead to the configuration of a task. Is there something like a *strict mode* that in my case throws a warning when defining a function named `jar`?